# SqlException: Invalid object name c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to connect to localDB in my .net core 2.0 web app. I have created a local db using SQL express.

My appsettings.json looks like this

```
{
"Logging": {
"IncludeScopes": false,
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Warning"
}
},

"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Shopping;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
}

}
```

My Context file looks like this

```
    public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext(DbContextOptions<ProductContext> options) 
        :base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

My startup file passes context like this

```
services.AddDbContext<ProductContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

When I am trying to get my products from the Database

```
        try
        {
            var d = await _context.Products.ToListAsync();
            return View(d);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

I get this exception thrown

> "Invalid object name 'Products'."

I am also adding my database image here

[image]

I am assuming it has something to do with the database connection?

How do I give path to the file?

Comment: can you please post your Product table schema and Product Model?

Comment: I don't think this is a database connection problem. Connection problems are like `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like you have no table `Products` in the Database.

1. It may be necessary to specify a different table name using the table mapping attribute (`[Table("Product")]`) on Model or to start migration / initialization on the database, if this has not already happened.
2. If there was a problem with the connection - the error would be exactly this, but it looks like you are getting an error (`"Invalid object name 'Products'."`) directly from the sql server

Comment: I have added the database as an image file. You can see that I have a table there.

Comment: Name of table is Product, but you use Product**S**

Comment: Add attribute from answer [Table("Product")] on your model class - This should help.

Comment: @AntonGorbunov Thanks. By mistake I have made change in db name and after lot of debugging, finally from your comment, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fluent API in `OnModelCreating` method of `ProductContext` to map database table with your model. This way you don't need to add attributes in you models.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .ToTable("Product");
    }
```